# Best way to return null from a method?

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

I need to get the hostname of the machine where the code is running. I have a method like this:

```
private static final String getHostName() {
    try {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName().toLowerCase();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        logger.logError("error = ", ex);
    }

    // this looks pretty odd to me, are there any better options?
    // like with guava or apache commons?
    return null;
}
```

And this is the way I am using above `getHostName()` method

```
private static String findData() {
    String host = getHostName();
    if(host != null) {
        // do something
    }
    // otherwise do something else
}
```

My question is - returning null looks pretty odd to me. Are there any other options with Guava or Apache Commons that I can use here?

Comment: What's wrong with bubbling up the exception?

Comment: Well, sometimes you don't want to bubble up the exception!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to throw an Exception and want to clearly handle cases where the value is missing, you can return an [`Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)

```
private static final Optional<String> getHostName() {
    try {
        return Optional.of(
            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName().toLowerCase());
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        logger.logError("error = ", ex);
        return Optional.absent();
    }
}
```

The client code would look like this:

```
private static String findData() {
    Optional<String> optionalHost = getHostName();
    if (optionalHost.isPresent()) {
        String host = optionalHost.get();
        // do something
    } else {
        // otherwise do something else
    }
}
```

More info about avoiding and handling null [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Optional. Can I use Optional in getHostname method instead of using in findData method?

Comment: Now it makes more sense. Also, how does my findData method will look like then? There will be some change to get the data from Optional right?

Answer (score 3):

If you are expecting callers to handle this case, then you can either use `Optional` (either from Guava or from JDK 8), or else simply let the exception bubble up (with or without logging it first).

If you are not expecting this case to ever arise, and you don't expect callers to handle it, but you're simply trying to satisfy the "catch or specify" requirement, then you can wrap it in an unchecked exception and raise that.

Answer (score 1):

That returning null looks odd to you shows that you have the right feeling. Never return null because you have to handle the return value (if x == null ...). So throw the exception and catch it at the proper place. If you don't want it to be signature relevant catch it early wrap it in a runtime exception and rethrow it. After that catch it at the proper place... did I already mentioned it?

Answer (score 1):

Guava provides the [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) class exactly for the purpose of not having to return `null`.

However, if you are already **using Java 8, please note that this also comes with an [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class** and you might prefer to use that one (for the sake of being independent from an external library).